# Compute from columns contain in 'with' clause

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find the number of late returned by film id as a % of total returns.

I've tried creating columns using the with clause, however it will not allow the columns that I've created to be used in the select statement

```
;with totalrentals as
(
select totalrentals = count(*), f.film_id , f.title 
from film f
inner join inventory i on i.film_id = f.film_id 
inner join rental r on r.inventory_id = i.[inventory_id]
group by f.film_id , f.title)
, laterentals as (
select  i.film_id, f.title,r.return_date,duedate=    (r.rental_date+f.rental_duration)
from rental r
inner join inventory i on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id 
inner join film f on f.film_id = i.film_id 
where r.return_date > (r.rental_date+f.rental_duration)
group by i.film_id,f.title,r.rental_date+f.rental_duration, r.return_date 
),
lr as
(
select Laterentals = count(*), f.film_id , f.title 
from laterentals
inner join film f on laterentals.film_id = f.film_id 
group by f.film_id, f.title 
)
select f.film_id, f.title, lr.laterentals ,tr.totalrentals ,pctlate =     (lr.Laterentals  /tr.totalrentals)*100
from film f 
inner join  lr on lr.film_id = f.film_id 
inner join totalrentals tr on tr.film_id  = f.film_id
inner join inventory i on i.film_id = f.film_id 
inner join rental r on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id 
group by f.film_id , f.title, lr.laterentals , tr.totalrentals 
order by f.film_id  asc
```

Expecting the report to output late returns as % of total returns

Instead, all pctlate values = 0

```
Film_ID   Title               Laterentals     Totalrentals    pctlate
1         ACADEMY DINOSAUR              7               23         0
2         ACE GOLDFINGER                5                7         0
```

Comment: `7 / 23 = 0`, because that's how integer division works in SQL Server. Try multiplying by `1.0` to force decimal division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that fields `lr.Laterentals` and `tr.totalrentals` are type of `INT`. Multiply by `1.0` and cast it to `DECIMAL`

```
select f.film_id, f.title, lr.laterentals ,tr.totalrentals ,pctlate =     
   CAST( 
       ( (lr.Laterentals * 1.0)  / (tr.totalrentals * 1.0)) * 100 
   AS DECIMAL(18, 3))
from film f
```

OR:

```
select f.film_id, f.title, lr.laterentals ,tr.totalrentals ,pctlate =     
   CAST( 
       ( CAST(lr.Laterentals AS DECIMAL(18,3))  / (CAST(tr.totalrentals AS DECIMAL 18,3 )))
           * 100 
   AS DECIMAL(18, 3))
from film f
```

You've got 0 as data type is `INT` When you use only integers in a division, then you will get integer division. In addition, `INT` does not have remainder, but `DECIMAL` has. However, if there is at least one number is `decimal` or other types with remainders, then  you will get floating point division

Let me show an example:

```
SELECT (1/2)
```

OUTPUT: `0`

```
SELECT ((1 * 1.0) / 2)
```

OUTPUT: `0.500000`

Comment: Well done. It feels like a bit of a hack though, can you explain it?

Comment: You will actually get fixed-point division. Floating-point division happens if floating-point numbers are involved -- if you want to force that, multiply by `1e` (which is a `FLOAT` constant). When calculating percentages, it doesn't make a big practical difference.